# I'm not able to see anything in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am not able to get the result that I want. when I open it, my frame goes on the top-left-hand side corner. when I expand it, it is blank. what am I doing wrong?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class About extends JFrame {
    public static JFrame contentPane;
    private JLabel textField;
    private JLabel VerNum;

    public About() {
        init();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new About().setVisible(true);
    }

    void init() {
        contentPane = new JFrame("About");
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        textField = new JLabel();
        textField.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new BufferedImage(16, 16, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)));
        textField.setBounds(324, 122, 766, 470);
        contentPane.add(textField);

        VerNum = new JLabel();
        VerNum.setBounds(473, 607, 130, 26);
        VerNum.setText("Version Number: test");
        contentPane.add(VerNum);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("");
        label.setBounds(162, 55, 61, 16);
        contentPane.add(label);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Close");
        btnNewButton.setBounds(6, 937, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Exit Program");
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(877, 937, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton_1);
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(311, 681, 61, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

        JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Get Latest SDK Version");
        btnNewButton_2.setBounds(324, 937, 232, 29);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton_2);
        contentPane.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Sorry if my code is very long.

Here are the screenshots:
Screenshot 1 (before I expand the frame):

[image: Screenshot1]
Screenshot 2 (after I expand the frame):

[image: Screenshot2]

I don't get any errors.

Comment: You have two entirely different `JFrame` objects, `About extends JFrame` … `new About()` and `contentPane = new JFrame("About")`

Comment: Please try to learn about [LayoutManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)s. It's very important in Swing. Please also provide correct names for your variables. (`VerNum` => `verNum`).

Comment: 1) Read all your text files and images into an application model before you start constructing the GUI.  2) Use [Swing layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to construct the GUI.  3) Separate your GUI code into small, easy for people to read, methods.  Don't construct the entire GUI in one long confusing method.

Comment: Please check that the edits I made to your code (see above) show the same problem as the first code you posted. (I think it will.) The reason I mentioned it is in regard to *"Sorry if my code is very long."*: we recommend people post a [mre], as the code is now. The art of making a good MRE takes a bit of time, but it is well worth doing. It helps hone the problem down to the minimum to still be able to see the problem, and is easiest to work with if it does not need any resources (like other custom classes, or images) and we can run the code here.

Comment: Is the idea to create something like seen in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aht07.png)? **Note:** the code from which that screenshot was made changes the `label` to a `TitledBorder`. It uses a `GridBagLayout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Objects;

public class About {
    public static JFrame contentPane;
    private JLabel textField;
    private JLabel VerNum;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new About();
    }
    public About() {
        init();

    }
    void init() {
        contentPane = new JFrame("About");
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        textField = new JLabel("ICON");
        //textField.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Objects.requireNonNull(About.class.getResource("/com/img/JUIT.png"))));
        textField.setBounds(324, 122, 766, 470);
        contentPane.add(textField);

        VerNum = new JLabel();
        VerNum.setBounds(473, 607, 130, 26);
        VerNum.setText("Version Number: "+ Installer.getInstallerVersion());
        contentPane.add(VerNum);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("");
        label.setBounds(162, 55, 61, 16);
        contentPane.add(label);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Close");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                contentPane.setVisible(false);

            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(6, 937, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Exit Program");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(877, 937, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton_1);
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(311, 681, 61, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

        JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Get Latest SDK Version");
        btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                URL url = null;
                InputStream is = null;
                try {
                    url = new URL("https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/973233/ver.txt");
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    is = url.openStream();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                lblNewLabel.setText(is.toString());

            }
        });
        btnNewButton_2.setBounds(324, 937, 232, 29);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton_2);
        contentPane.setVisible(true);
        contentPane.setSize(1200, 1200);
        contentPane.setPreferredSize(contentPane.getSize());
        contentPane.pack();
    }
}
```

I think for your txt file, try to use pastebin with raw url !

Comment: Thanks! I will Follow up With More Information

Comment: Thanks! it works but there's just a missing package definition. That's no problem.